# C++ anyway to handle onTouchHolding

Tags: c++, events, touch, handle

I'm using cocos2d-x 3.10, in this version we can easy to handle `onTouchBegan`, `onTouchMoved`, `onTouchEnd`, `onTouchCancel` by something like this

```
_touchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
_touchListener->onTouchBegan = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchBegan, this);
_touchListener->onTouchCancelled = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchCancel, this);
_touchListener->onTouchMoved = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchMoved, this);
_touchListener->onTouchEnded = CC_CALLBACK_2(GameScene::onTouchEnded, this);
```

But how about `onTouchHolding`? many thank friends

Comment: Doesn't `hold` start with `begin` and stop with `end`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `onTouchHolding` because there is no event that fires when nothing happens (i.e. not moving your finger).

If you want to see how long a touch has been held, you can set a flag in `onTouchBegan`. In your `update` method, you increment a member variable by `dt` if that flag is set. In your `onTouchEnded`, you would unset the flag.

Something like this:

```
void GameScene::update(float dt)
{
    if (_touchInProgress)
    {
        _holdTime += dt;
    }
}

bool GameScene::onTouchBegan(Touch *touch, Event *event)
{
    _holdTime = 0.0;
    _touchInProgress = true;
    return true;
}

void GameScene::onTouchEnded(Touch *touch, Event *event)
{
    _touchInProgress = false;
    if (_holdTime > kMyHoldTimeThreshold)
    {
        // Do something awesome
    }
}
```